# WPF I don't get binding between Label and Texblock to work

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I've been trying different approaches with no luck. So here's my issue: I want to bind what I type on a textblock to a label. Nothing special but i want to build something else on top of that. Here's my code:

MainWindow.Xaml

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name2, ElementName=window, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name2, ElementName=window, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private string _name2;

    public string Name2
    {
        get { return _name2; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _name2)
            {
                _name2 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name2");
            }
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

My expectation is to see the label changing as I typed on the textblock, I've done this many times using Xamarin but i can't get it to work on WPF. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you set the `DataContext`?

Comment: Hello @Sach and no. I tried before, probably did it wrong. Since I created my dependency property on MainWindow.xaml.cs, do i still need to set a data source on the XAML file? If yes, how?

Comment: Where is window (lowercase) declared?

Comment: @Peregrine that's something i added from one article i was reading and forgot to remove it. It does not work with or without it. Sorry i don't remember the article.

Comment: This really is a bizarre way of constructing databinding - in MVVM the usual way is to create a ViewModel class to hold the properties, and to set the DataContext of the window to an instance of this class.

Comment: @Peregrine agreed, with my experience with Xamarin that was my first approach. Since i did not get it to work I tried something simpler like this example to narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your binding to work, the `MainWindow` property `Name` must be set to "window".

```
<Window ...
        Name="window">
```

Then, in the constructor, set `DataContext`:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
}
```

### NOTE:

However, for data binding and `MVVM` to make sense, you should really consider using a `ViewModel` and separate `View` from the `ViewModel`.

### NOTE2:

You don't need to do both above, as pointed out by a commenter. Either of the two will suffice.

Comment: And yes, now that i know the basics i will follow MvvM best practices.

Comment: I will, it says i have to wait 1 minute.

Comment: Just to note: you don't need to set the data context if you're binding to the object using ElementName. You'll typically use one approach or the other, but not both.